# iOS Wierd Splash Screen Bug

Tags: ios, splash-screen

I'm trying to get my app's splash screen to be displayed correctly instead of a black screen for a few seconds before the splash screen. I have made 3 implementations of the splash screen; issues with each are listed below:

**XIB**: This only displays the background color of the splash screen for a few seconds and then the rest of the splash is loaded.

**XIB + Asset Catalog**: For iPhone 5 running iOS 8: if the phone is currently displaying the blue navigation bar and the app is opened from a url while in the background, a black screen will be displayed before the splash.

**Storyboard**: On all models: this displays a black splash screen before the actual one loads.

Is this an iOS bug or am I implementing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the logic that is executed when the application is launched - `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. If it takes significant time to execute the code in it, then this might be the problem. It is always recommended to return fast and execute any additional logic on a later moment.

Answer (score 0):

It's so quite simple! I had such bug and I solved it.

You should enable "Enable Initial View Controller" to see splash screen

[image: Enable Initial View Controller]

Comment: I had tried this at the time and did not solve the issue